# convert a string to array on javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hello I have a string like that :

> Black,Gray,White,Brown,Beige,Red,Pink,Orange,Blue,Green,Purple,Sliver,Multi

how can I convert to array

> color:["Black","Gray","White","Brown","Beige","Red","Pink","Orange","Blue","Green","Purple","Sliver","Multi"]

thanks

Comment: Use split `var arr = string.split(',')`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
var string = "Black,Gray,White,Brown,Beige,Red,Pink,Orange,Blue,Green,Purple,Sliver,Multi";
var colors = string.split(',');

console.log(colors);
```